# Image path not saved in database in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to put the file path to database, I already uploaded the file but I don't know how to get the path of the file to put it in the database? I already searched SOF!!!

Update_profile Controller

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

ini_set("display_errors",1);

class Update_profile extends CI_Controller {


     function __construct()
     {
          // Call the Model constructor
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->is_login();
          $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        //  $this->load->model('Edit_profile'); 
          $this->load->model('Insert_article');      
     }


    public  function index() {

    //  $this->load->view('header2');
        $this->load->view('edit_profile');

    }// index function ends

    public function is_login() {

      $is_login=$this->session->userdata('is_login');
      if(!isset($is_login) || $is_login !=true)
      {
        //don't echo the message from controller 
        echo "you don't have permission to access this page <a href=../Homecontroller/index/>Login</a>";
        die();
      }
  } //is_login function ends

  // function to upload images
    function upload()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        //post image
        $img=$this->input->post("filename");
        //set preferences
        $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // for encrypting the name
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/large/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size']    = '10248';

        //load moadel ********
        $this->load->model('Edit_profile');
        //load upload class library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        //$this->upload->do_upload('filename') will upload selected file to destiny folder
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            // case - failure
            $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $upload_error);
        }
        else
        {
            // case - success
            //callback  returns an array of data related to the uploaded file like the file name, path, size etc
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            //return $upload_data;
            //print_r($upload_data);
            // call to model function *********
            $data['images'] = $this->Edit_profile->upload_image();

            $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);

        }
    }


} //class ends   
?>
```

My model to update profile

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

ini_set("display_errors",1);

class Edit_profile extends CI_Model {


  var $file_path;
  var $file_path_url;

 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
      $this->file_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../upload/large');
      $this->file_path_url = base_url().'upload/large/';
      //$this->is_login();
      //$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));


 }

    public function upload_image()  
  {  
    $files = scandir($this->file_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));
    $images = array();
    foreach ($files as $file){
    $images [] = array(
      'url' => $this->file_path_url . $file,
      'thumb_url' => $this->file_path_url . 'thumbs/' .$file
     );

    }
    return $images;


  }
function insert_new_post($img)
        {
            $query_insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_usrs (profile_picture) VALUES (?)";
            $this->db->query($query_insert);

        }


}
```

i have tbl_usrs with 35 fields and profile_picture is for uploading profile pic??

Comment: From where insert_new_post() is called ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging to narrow down the problem?  What specific symptoms (i.e. error messages, noticeable behavior, etc.) are you seeing for the problem?

Comment: @MikeBrant i have done some debugging didn't get errors but i am getting error Column 'profile_picture' cannot be null i will update my code too see why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html/)

Add in your constants file

```
define('LARGEPATH','./upload/large/');
define('THUMBPATH','./upload/thumb/');
```

controller

```
    $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // for encrypting the name
    $config['upload_path'] = LARGEPATH;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
    $config['max_size']    = '10248';



 $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
 $data['images'] = $this->Edit_profile->upload_image($upload_data);
 $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);
```

Edit_profile Model

```
   public function upload_image($data)  
  {  
      $filePath = ltrim(LARGEPATH.$data['file_name'],'.');
       $query_insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_usrs (profile_picture) VALUES (".$filepath.")";
        $this->db->query($query_insert);

  }
```

If you want to resize image 
[http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html/)

Comment: Array ( [file_name] => bc84240d53934f1821f2ead89dd5e06c.jpg [file_type] => image/jpeg [file_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/ko/upload/large/ [full_path] => C:/xampp/htdocs/ko/upload/large/bc84240d53934f1821f2ead89dd5e06c.jpg [raw_name] => bc84240d53934f1821f2ead89dd5e06c [orig_name] => 32.jpg [client_name] => 32.jpg [file_ext] => .jpg [file_size] => 1771.4 [is_image] => 1 [image_width] => 2448 [image_height] => .. 
i am getting like above.Image is uploaded successfully but path not saved in DB
 file_path there image is uploaded but that path is not saved in database

Comment: which version of CI your are using ?

Comment: ok save file_name in your database which is unique . And when showing to user add your upload path with base url Or just save this to your db

Comment: i am getting this error INSERT INTO `tbl_usrs` (`profile_picture`) VALUES (/upload/large/)